# I need to get Shopify to change the product description when you change the variant. Is there a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, variant

I am sure every Shopify newbie eventually gets to this point. On the Product page I need the Description to change when the Variant changes. In other words, if the customer chooses "A - Grade" from the Condition pull-down I need the Description to change to a Grade A Description. Same with grade B and C.

if customer chooses Grade A
change product description

I achieved this already by putting an IF statement in the Shopify->Sections->product-template.liquid. However, this solution requires a screen refresh which does not look good to the customer. Makes the page look broken.

```
{% if product.selected_variant.option1 == "A - Grade" %}
    <B>A-GRADE</B>: Very light use, if any, ...
{% endif %}
{% if product.selected_variant.option1 == "B - Grade" %}
    <B>B-GRADE</B>: Normal use, no dings or dents...
{% endif %}
{% if product.selected_variant.option1 == "C - Grade" %}
    <B>C-GRADE</B>: Medium to heavy use, might ...
{% endif %}
```

Again, this requires a page-refresh. Even if you code the refresh to happen automatically it still looks bad especially if the customer is on a slower connection.

There is already some code in the themes.js that changes the price and image when you select a new varriant:

```
this.$container.on('variantChange' + this.settings.namespace, this._updateAddToCart.bind(this));
this.$container.on('variantImageChange' + this.settings.namespace, this._updateImages.bind(this));
this.$container.on('variantPriceChange' + this.settings.namespace, this._updatePrice.bind(this));
this.$container.on('variantSKUChange' + this.settings.namespace, this._updateSKU.bind(this));
```

I do not know any javascript so I am lost. Can't we just copy the existing variantPriceChange function and change it into a variantDescriptionChange?

Comment: You need to assign some HTML id or class to descriptions and code into _updateAddToCart this function in your theme.js file.